# jQuery Datepicker - Dynamically change selectable dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jQuery datepicker and I currently have this code:

```
$("#dateObj").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: findDateAvailable
});
```

where `findDateAvailable` is a function which checks if the date is in an array and if not, makes the date not selectable.

My question is: how do I change which dates are 'active' and can be selected without changing my array and then re-creating the datepicker object?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `refresh` method of the datepicker widget.

> Redraw the date picker, after having made some external modifications.
>   This method does not accept any arguments.

Reference here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh

You can use it in your script by using:

```
$("#dateObj").datepicker("refresh");
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ChM6D/2/